# Invalid Userid or postid etc. Error on Editing the URL in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So i am trying to set a validation in post model if someone tries to edit in the url and enter another post number like:
from this

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/1
```

to this

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/112318278
```

and when user enter it should show some error msg or redirect to some other page or stuff...
how to do that ?

Comment: Your question is not very clear as to the problem, but in ruby on rails you can redirect to another page using the `redirect_to` function, detailed here https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.3/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't. Take StackOverflow for example
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73189649` if I want to change this to a different id, I can and it will work `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73189659`

Second, your backend will attempt at finding the post with the given id, from your controller. One thing you could do is put a rescue clause in the finder.
(this is one of many ways to do it, but it's the simplest)

```
def find_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id]) # => This will raise an error if the post does not exist
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e # => This will rescue that error, and send the user to a different page, and not the Rails' 404 page
  redirect_to(some_path, notice: 'This post does not exist')
end
```